# Get dragged / saved items state back from Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, ajax, jquery-ui

Ok i saw many post's on how to serialize the value of dragged items to get hash and they tell how to save them. Now the question is how do i persist the dragged items the next time when user log's in using the has value that i got
eg:

```
  <ul class="list">
        <li id="id_1">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_2">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_3">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="id_4">
            <div class="item ui-corner-all ui-widget">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

which on serialize will give

```
"id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3&id[]=4"
```

Now think that i saved it to Sql server database in a single field called SortOrder.
 **Now how do i get the items to these order again ?**
the code to make these sort is below,without which people didn't know which library i had used to sort and serialize

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".list li").css("cursor", "move");
        $(".list").sortable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You are using JQuery sortable to sort these?  And what control originally rendered this, a repeater or listview or what?  Or was it all client-side?

Comment: lol u can see the code above , that is the one i am talking about. Jqueryui sortable is the plugin used.let me add some more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what Brian is saying is that your table should look like this, if they were sorted in ascending order by the user:

ID Sort Order

1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

If they were sorted in descending order by the user, the table would look like this:

ID Sort Order

1  4
2  3
3  2
4  1

Then, when you query the database, you would do

```
SELECT [ID], [Sort Order]
FROM [thetable]
ORDER BY [Sort Order]
```

and the list would be sorted by the server.

You can then just output the data in the order the server code provides it in.

Comment: i have no problems in getting the data back. Once i get the data back , how would i re arrange them in that order. Could u show some code sample,simply said i give u this id[]=2&id[]=4&id[]=1&id[]=2 and i tell u to sort the items in that order with jquery! show me the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing a single field, can you store a SortOrder column with the data?  You can update the DB with the new sort order, and when you query data from the DB, order it by the sort order.  Otherwise, in code, you must do a programmatic sort ordering of data, querying the data into something, then looping through and copying the data to another array/list that's sorted based on this one field.

HTH.

Comment: that pretty much confused me. the best way to talk to a programmer is by code. could u put togather a code to show me what u meant? but u could show me a example of saving value into cookie and reading from that again to get sorted items index

Comment: Hmm still no answers i would better leave this here for someone else to answer